# Lollipop vs Nougat Runtime directory permission to external storage folder

Tags: android, android-storage

I have a code that runs fine in Lollipop device but don't do anything in Nougat

```
private ArrayList<PDFDoc> getPDFs() {
    File downloadsFolder=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    if (downloadsFolder.exists()) {
        //GET ALL FILES IN DOWNLOAD FOLDER
        File[] files = downloadsFolder.listFiles();

        //LOOP THRU THOSE FILES GETTING NAME AND URI
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];

            if (file.getPath().endsWith("pdf")) {
                pdfDoc = new PDFDoc();
                pdfDoc.setName(file.getName());
                pdfDoc.setPath(file.getAbsolutePath());

                pdfDocs.add(pdfDoc);
            }

        }
    }

    return pdfDocs;
}
```

This block runs fine with desired result in lollipop but not in Nougat, kindly help me out with genuine changes or addition.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the method getPDFs() you need to check whether the storage permission is granted by the user or not.
From android marshmallow, only defining the permissions in Manifest file will not work you need to ask for the permission on runtime.

So first you need to check if the device running the app is marshmallow or above. You can do it by using this code.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
  //ask for permission here 
}
```

For asking the runtime permission you can use the following code.

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted
}
```

You have to do this for the storage permission. I copied the above code from the Android Developer's Page.

For more details check [Requesting App's permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add runtime permissions

```
private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 786;

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {            
        //call func here
    }
  }     

private void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            //call func here
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**AppConstants**

```
public static final String CAMERA_PERMISSION = CAMERA;
public static final String READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION = READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
public static final String WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
public static final String LOCATION_PERMISSION = ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
public static final String READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION= READ_PHONE_STATE;
```

**Call this Function From your (Activity OR Fragment OR Button) for checking the permissions**

```
  //Getting permission here
public boolean needPermission() {
    try {
        int readPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, AppConstants.READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION);
        int location = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, AppConstants.LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        if (readPhoneState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && location == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (readPhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                AppGlobal.checkSinglePermission(this, AppConstants.READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION);
            } else if (location != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                AppGlobal.checkSinglePermission(this, AppConstants.LOCATION_PERMISSION);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**This function will check permission type**

```
  //Check single permission
public static boolean checkSinglePermission(final Context context, String permissionType) {
    ArrayList<String> permissionList = new ArrayList<>();
    String type = "";

    if (permissionType != null) {
        if (permissionType.equals(AppConstants.CAMERA_PERMISSION)) {
            type = permissionType;
        }
        if (permissionType.equals(AppConstants.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION)) {
            type = permissionType;
        }
        if (permissionType.equals(AppConstants.WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION)) {
            type = permissionType;
        }
        if (permissionType.equals(AppConstants.READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION)) {
            type = permissionType;
        }
        if (permissionType.equals(AppConstants.LOCATION_PERMISSION)) {
            type = permissionType;
        }

        int getPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, type);

        if (getPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionList.add(type);
            if (!permissionList.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, permissionList.toArray
                        (new String[permissionList.size()]), SINGLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

**Then you will get permission success and failure  response in this *onRequestPermissionsResult()***

```
 //Permission request result here
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {
            AppLog.e("denied" + permission);//denied
            needPermission();//needed permission for getting Country code

        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                AppLog.e("allowed" + permission);//allowed
                needPermission();//set data
            } else {
                //set to never ask again
                AppLog.e("set to never ask again" + permission);
                AppDialog.showAlertDialog(this, null,
                        getString(R.string.read_phone_state_permission_txt), getString(R.string.txt_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                AppGlobal.permissionSettingView(LoginActivity.this);

                            }
                        });

            }
        }

    }
}
```